# how escape all chars with ALT

Tags: php, jquery, html, regex

in alphabet FR have for example: é and in alphabet GER have: ö etc.
how can i rid all chars with ALT on keybord? 
I can use:

```
$addr = strtr($addr, "äåö", "aao");
```

but i dont know all alphabets.

Comment: dont! use utf-8 for all encodings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna assume you want a PHP answer given your question tags. This seems to cover all of them that I know/heard off

```
$text = "Yôûr téxt wíth àccènts :)";
$search = explode(",","ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,e,i,ø,u");
$replace = explode(",","c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u");
$text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

Source: http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/removing-accented-utf-8-characters-with-php/

Answer (score 3):

If you know your input charset and you want to pare down to the ASCII set only, you could use `iconv`. Assuming your input is UTF-8:

```
$text = "äåö";
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

This example would output `aao`.

Be aware that `iconv` can sometimes be brittle when confronted with characters that don't have rough ASCII equivalents (though this behavior seems to have improved quite a bit lately).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier solution:

```
$output = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$input);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to remove the accents (äáàāąãåâ => a), not remove the characters.